# How to update the loop in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a very simple View and within the view I am running a loop having some text. I just want to reload the content within the loop whenever the viewmodel data is changing.

view

```
import SwiftUI
struct DateTimeSelectionView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var dateTimeSelectionModel = DateTimeSelectionViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                self.dateTimeSelectionModel.updateRecord()
                dateTimeSelectionModel.objectWillChange.send()
            } label: {
                Text("Update Record")
            }
            

            ForEach(0..<(dateTimeSelectionModel.data.count)) { index in
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello \(index)")
                }
                
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct DateTimeSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DateTimeSelectionView()
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
import Foundation

class DateTimeSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data:[Int] = Array(0...10)
    
    func updateRecord() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
            self.data.append(12)
            self.data.append(13)
            self.data.append(14)
        })
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach, using `StateObject` and `enumerated()`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        DateTimeSelectionView()
    }
}

struct DateTimeSelectionView: View {
    
    @StateObject var dateTimeSelectionModel = DateTimeSelectionViewModel() // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                dateTimeSelectionModel.updateRecord() // <-- here, just this
            } label: {
                Text("Update Record")
            }
            ForEach(Array(dateTimeSelectionModel.data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { item, index in   // <-- here
                VStack {
                    Text("Hello \(index)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class DateTimeSelectionViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data:[Int] = Array(0...10)
    
    func updateRecord() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1, execute: {
            self.data.append(12)
            self.data.append(13)
            self.data.append(14)
        })
    }
}
```

You could also use:

```
ForEach(dateTimeSelectionModel.data.indices, id: \.self) { index in   // <-- here
    VStack {
        Text("Hello \(index)")
    }
}
```

Note, it is not recommended to use this:

```
ForEach(0..<(dateTimeSelectionModel.data.count), id: \.self) { index in
```

Be aware of the difference between this, with `item`, that is the contents of the array:

```
        ForEach(dateTimeSelectionModel.data, id: \.self) { item in
            VStack {
                Text("Hello \(item)")
            }
        }
```

and this with `index`, the index of the array elements:

```
        ForEach(dateTimeSelectionModel.data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
            VStack {
                Text("Hello \(index)")
            }
        }
```